# Using pybind11 to expose C++ functionality with preexisting embedded python interpreter

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am trying this type of coding for the first time and hence please pardon my lack of knowledge.

Requirement: I have a C++ code in which I have embedded python interpreter so that i can import/use python libraries with C++ using pybind11. Further, I want to make a wrapper of this complete C++ code (along with python interpreter part) and expose it to python as a module. Consider the below example for clarity:

```
**Main_code.cpp:**

    #include <iostream>
    #include <pybind11/embed.h> // everything needed for embedding
    
    int main() {
        pybind11::scoped_interpreter guard{}; // start the interpreter and keep it alive
        pybind11::module sys = pybind11::module::import("sys");
        pybind11::print(sys.attr("path"));
        return 0;
    }
```

I want to expose this code to python (say as a module named Cpp_func) and import in py script using "import Cpp_func"

What I have tried till now:
Using pybind11, I could manage to extend a sample cpp code without python interpreter embedded to python. Example was taken from the pybind11 docs https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html 'Creating bindings for a simple function' section. But I am unable to figure out how to do the same when a python interpreter is already embedded into C++ code.

Hope my requirement is clear. Any comments on this would be really helpful!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scoped_interpreter_guard` is just a [RAII wrapper](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/b2f52225fa3dd546ea8475eeee397d5c1342a32a/include/pybind11/embed.h#L183-L201) around `initialize_interpreter` and `finalize_interpreter`. You can just call `finalize_interpreter` yourself instead of `Py_Finalize`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I don't understand how this would help in achieving my requirement. Could you please provide some more details? @Botje

Comment: Why can't you now create bindings? What goes wrong? You have to define a new module using the `PYBIND11_MODULE` macro and fill its contents with definitions. When you `import` the corresponding module from Python, the initialization code will run and you should be able to access the contents of the module.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: You shouldn't try to (re) initialize the interpreter inside a function. You only need to call finalize_interpreter at the end of the program.